# Does Method.invoke create another thread of execution?

Tags: java, reflection

Does the method.invoke function create another thread of execution?  Because when I used it to call a GUI application's main method, the invoke method returned immediately and the program and the GUI application were running at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

The behaviour you observe is caused by the fact that the GUI library starts an Event Dispatch Thread when initialized, and all following GUI-related work is performed by that thread.

**EDIT** Here is a simple Swing GUI application:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello, world!");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Main method returns");
    }
}
```

If you run it, you will see that all these methods are non-blocking, therefore `main` method returns immediately after GUI is set up, and further work is performed by Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: But, when does the invoke method actually return? What makes it return?

Comment: Yup, that answers it. Thanks.

Comment: It's also not thread-safe to use Swing on the main thread. Use `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater` to get single-threaded on the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) (as any half-decent Swing book, tutorial or other documentation should tell you).

Answer (score 1):

No. **Method.invoke** is working just like a normal method. If it is not you expect, maybe it throws Exception. Did you wrap the invocation?

Also, a snippet will help a lot